# Derivations of $f(t,y(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm working on a IVP
$$
y'(t) = f(t,y), \\
y(t_0) = y_0
$$
and am struggling with the derivatives (I need them for a Taylor expansion). I hope this isn't a dumb question , but can someone tell me if the following is correct? That would be very helpful!

$$
\frac{d^3y}{dt^3} = y'''(t) = \frac{d^2f}{dt^2} =\\
        = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t^2} + 
        2 \cdot \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial t} \cdot f + 
        \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} \cdot f^2 +
        \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + 
        \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)^2 \cdot f
$$

Comment: Yes, it's correct.